# Can topic model be used to classify documents ?

Tags: topic-models

Is dynamic topic model can be used to label data ? I divided a unlabeled dataset into training and testing sets. Is it rational to label the training data with dynamic topic model (I want to take time factor into account.) and then classify testing data according to this training set ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can.

Note that topic modelling is a technique of *unsupervised learning*; therefore the notion of a "training set" and a "testing set" do not apply for topic modelling. But you can learn topics on a part of the data and use the so-gained topics to classify the rest of the data as well.